# What's the correct way to use import?

Tags: python

I have my modules in the following example structure:

```
myapp
   --- application
      -- application.py
      -- __init__.py
   --- converter
       --  converter.py
       -- __init__.py
   --- gui
        --- panel.py
        --- __init__.py
```

Now if I am in panel.py how should I import converter.py? would it be

1. from myapp.converter import converter? (assuming sys.path is set)
2. from converter import converter (assuming sys.path is set
3. import converter (assuming sys.path is set)

Do these points depend on where the main python application is run from? i.e. if converter.py was the program to run or panel.py was the program to run?

Comment: `application/application.py` and `converter/converter.py` seems a bit redundant. Wouldn't it be cleaner to add `application.py` and `converter.py` modules to the `myapp` package?

Comment: I would agree with application but not converter, well this layout is just an example and not a real thing, but my reasoning is that I can imagine having numberconverter, floatconverter, charconverter etc.. or something like that in a  package, however you only have a single application which can sit on the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefer full paths over relative paths, so in my opinion the first one is the best way to do it, although you should consider adding an alias since *converter* appears twice.

```
from myapp.converter import converter as conv
```

Furthermore you can look up the Python recommandation (PEP8)
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: As @Guybrush pointed out, myapp would need to be a package in this case though; otherwise import from your root package

Comment: okay so absolute is the recommended way, the second option is relative imports but if I can have an absolute package then I should go for that

Comment: Absolute imports can be very confusing especially when you have a module (directory) that has the same name than another module (a file inside that directory). In the current case, e.g. `import converter` depends on what's in your PYTHON_PATH. With relative imports, `from . import converter` only depends on the file in which this statement is written.

Answer (score 1):

If `myapp` is not a module (ie. does not have `__init__.py` at its root), there is no way to import something from e.g. `converter` inside e.g. `panel.py` unless `converter` (or a parent module) is added to the `PYTHON_PATH`.

If `myapp` is a module (has `__init__.py`), you can use relative imports: 
`from ..converter import converter`.

Relative imports indicate explicitly that you want to use something that is "local", and is usually the way to go. 
See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references for an example.

**Updated**: Fixed terminology to make things easier ;)